# PowerShell Output

Tags: file, powershell, output

So, I am fairly new to PowerShell and need to create a script to rename the computers in our office. That portion of the script works. The part I am having trouble with is the output.

I have this set in task scheduler, but when it runs I do not see if the rename was successful. Below is my script and below that is what goes into the text file.

```
start-transcript -path C:\Users\abhagwandin.SENECA\Desktop\RenameResults.txt
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\Users\abhagwandin.SENECA\Desktop\Computer Desktop Names Test.csv" -Header OldName, NewName
Foreach ($name in $CSV)


{
write-output $name

netdom renamecomputer $name.OldName /newname: $name.NewName /userd: admin /passwordd: pass /usero: admin /passwordo: pass /reboot /force
}



stop-transcript
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript Start
Start time: 20150520154216
Username  : 
Machine   :  (Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1) 
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\abhagwandin.SENECA\Desktop\RenameRe
sults.txt
OldName                                 NewName                                
-------                                 -------                                
JFLAHNYCD1                              JFLAHERTY                              
**********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript End
End time: 20150520154218
**********************
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that renaming a computer through a cmdline command in powershell instead of using the built in cmdlets can give problems with the output if you don't parse the output (and preferably create a new object for it)?

Why don't you use rename-computer or the rename() method of the win32_computersystem wmi class? Both can be used remotely so you don't even have to schedule tasks that way.

Just create an input file with the current name and the desired names and use a loop to process them.